# Unity API minimum Level Android platform

Tags: android, unity3d

в билде у меня от 16 до 25 (API Level) мне необходимо 15, в списке его нету, что необходимо сделать что бы появился API Level 15?, пробовал в SDK Manager скачивать эту платформу, пк перезагрузил, не появилась, используется tools_r25.2.3-windows и JDK 8 64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Читаем [патч ноуты](https://unity3d.com/ru/unity/whats-new/unity-5.6.0).

> 5.6.0f3 Release Notes (Full)
>
> System Requirement Changes
>
> - Android minimum version supported updated to 4.1 (JellyBean)

Так что, единственный вариант - поставить старую версию Unity.